# Applying Ito isometry to stochastic integrals

Tags: expectation, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $\{W_x\}_{x \in [0,t]}$ be a Wiener process and $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ exponential functions (with different coefficients inside). Let $s$ be a positive number, with $0<s<t$.

I would like to calculate the following expectation value:

$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t \int_0^s f(x)f(y)g(W_x)g(W_y)\, dW_x \, dW_y \right]$

Since the two integrals are not defined on the same interval, I guess I can't use the Ito isometry, at least in its most common form. I am wondering if there are any other useful tricks to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^t \int_0^s f(x)f(y)g(W_x)g(W_y)\, dW_x \, dW_y$ can be rewritten as 
 $\int_0^t \int_0^t 1_{y<s}f(x)f(y)g(W_x)g(W_y)\, dW_x \, dW_y$

Then you can apply the isometry on $X_t$ and $Y_t$ where

$X_t=f(x)g(W_x)$

and $Y_t=1_{t<s}f(y)g(W_y)$

Comment: Thanks. So the expectation value should give

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t\int_0^t 1_{y<s}\,f(x)f(y)g(W_x)g(W_y)\,dW_x\,dW_y  \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t 1_{x<s}\,f(x)f(x)g(W_x)g(W_x)\,dx  \right] = \int_0^s f(x)f(x) \,\mathbb{E}\left[g(W_x)g(W_x)\right]\,dx$$


Is it correct? 

Then I could also have split the integral in $[0,t]$ in two integrals, defined respectively in $[0,s]$ and $[s,t]$, and assumed that the expectation value of the second one multiplied by another integral in $[0,s]$ is zero. Would there have been any reason to assume it at the beginning?